# hadoop input path specify folder range

Tags: java, input, hadoop, mapreduce

How do I specify a generic input path for my map reduce.

Example folder structure is:

```
   folderA/folderB/folderC/mainfolder/date/day/data files
```

There are many date folders and many days folders.

I want to drill down within a specific range of date folders folder and then pick up specific range of data files. If I try

```
'folderA/folderB/folderC/mainfolder/*/*'
```

This will read all files. I want to specify a date forlder range i.e read all files within 13-06-01 and 13-06-25 and and ignore all other date folders. How do I do that?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

If you are providing

```
'folderA/folderB/folderC/mainfolder/*/*'
```

as an input and want to filter out specific paths, you might want to create a custom PathFilter

In [FileInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html) you have this function-

---

```
static void setInputPathFilter (JobConf conf, Class<? extends PathFilter> filter)
Info: Set a PathFilter to be applied to the input paths for the map-reduce job
```

---

For e.g.

```
public static class CustomPathFilter implements PathFilter {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(Path path) {
        //you can implement your logic for finding the valid range of paths here.
        //The valid range of dates and days for directories and files can be input 
        //as arguments to the job.
        //Return true if you find a match or else return false.
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Register the PathFilter like this -

```
FileInputFormat.setInputPathFilter(job, CustomPathFilter.class);
```

Comment: Cana I use a regex in the input file path to specify a range?

Comment: @user2441441: For e.g.: If you use 'folderA/folderB/folderC/mainfolder/*/*', all the files will be considered that matches /*/*, and when you filter by your custom date range in the PathFilter, only specific files would get processed. If you are looking for something else, please reply. Thanks!